# Running java jar classes with python using javabridge

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, jakarta-ee, java-bridge-method

I am trying to invoke some classes that are in jar file from python.I have set path and trying to run it like this :

```
import javabridge as jv
path=r'D:\myFiles\swinglibrary-1.9.5.jar'
jars = jv.JARS+[path]
jv.start_vm(run_headless=True,class_path=jars)
print(str(jv.get_static_field("org.robotframework.swing.SwingLibrary","runKeyword", a)))
```

I get this below error when i execute this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    print(str(javabridge.get_static_field("org.robotframework.swing.SwingLibrary", "runKeyword", a)))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 952, in get_static_field
    raise JavaException(jexception)
JavaException: org.robotframework.swing.SwingLibrary
```

I am not sure how to invoke a class in a jar using javabridge.Can anyone help me out with this?